# Как определить путь к файлу?

Tags: java, java-ee

Как определить путь к файлу относительно веб-приложения. Например, в WEB-INF хранится config.xml файл с конфигурациями базы данных. Надо из сервлета определить путь config.xml.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давно не писал сервлеты - запамятовал уже :)

Впишите в логах своего сервлета/JSP строчку:

```
ServletContext.getRealPath("\\");
```

и вы получите путь корня контекста в файловой системе сервера, относительно него уже и позиционируйте свой файл.

Comment: наверное, не совсем то, что я хочу. я не хочу привязываться к физическим директориям, знаю, что есть myClass.class.getRealPath().
Как потом подняться вверх по каталогам? ../ ?

Comment: Ну если физический путь корня будет что-то типа `~/myfolder/myserver`, то вам надо указать `/web-inf/config.xml` и это будет в реальной системе указывать на путь `~/myfolder/myserver/web-inf/config.xml`, нет?

Comment: да, так и есть. спасибо